# Does the google people api offer query or search functionality?

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client, google-people-api

Using the google apis client library "gapi" and trying to search for users by email. I found the `gapi.client.people.people.connections.list` method, but it doesn't seem to accept a query or searching capability.

So is my option to just get all contacts and sort/query them on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct there is no way to do a search on the contract list method.   You will need to download all of the users contacts and search them locally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching users by mail address in my domain company source using the [people.searchDirectoryPeople](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchDirectoryPeople). You simply need to set the mail address in the `query` field, I've also selected `DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE` to get the company profile and not the users modified field.